# Navigation Bar "back" Button to dismiss Modal View

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, modalviewcontroller

I´m trying to create something like an own "adBanner" for a website in my app.

The Banner is a Button with an image, which is actually the banner graphic.

```
[_adBanner setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_banner.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_adBanner.opaque = YES; 
[self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
[(UIButton*) _adBanner addTarget:self action:@selector(showWebView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[_adBanner release];
```

here is my function for flipping the view

```
- (IBAction)showWebView:(id)sender {    

XLog ("Button Clicked");

WebViewController *_webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];


_webViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];
```

}

in my _webViewController I want to show a UIWebView with an url

First I coded a Navigation Bar with Title

WebViewController.m :

```
// Setting Navigation Bar
CGRect navBarRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f);
navBar = [ [ UINavigationBar alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(navBarRect.origin.x, navBarRect.origin.y, navBarRect.size.width, 45.0f)];
[ navBar setDelegate: self.view ];
[ self.view addSubview: navBar ];
[ navBar release];

// Setting TitleString
NSString* adClientTitleString = [ [ NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Client" ];
// Setting Title
[ navBar pushNavigationItem: [ [ UINavigationItem alloc ] initWithTitle:adClientTitleString ] ];
[ navBar setDelegate: self];
```

and now I created a back Button

```
[ navBar showButtonsWithLeftTitle: @"Zurück" rightTitle:nil leftBack: YES];
```

My question Is How I can make my back Button to dismiss the Modal View again ?
Or how can I set the action ?? Thank You for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use modal view controller, then you can dismiss it with dismissModalViewController method of a WebViewController class.

Other way is to use UINavigationController. You may [check](http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/monotouch-controllers-by-example/uinavigationcontroller-by-example.aspx) examples for this controller.

To make left button work you should also implement

`- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar*)navbar buttonClicked:(int)button`

method.

Answer (score 6):

If you use this code after that then it will work.

```
    navBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem =[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonItemToDismissModal)];


-(void)backButtonItemToDismissModal{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```